# Make asp.net error page point to the outermost exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.6

This is my asp.net page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("hello");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("world", ex);
    }

}
```

When I run it, the asp.net error page says an error is thrown from Line 14, giving error message "hello". I expect to see error message "world" instead.

[image: the asp.net error page says an error is thrown from Line 14, giving error message "hello"]

I recall in tha past the error page would say the error is from `throw new Exception("world", ex);`. Maybe it's changed in Visual Studio 2015?

Do I remember wrong? Is there an option to let the error page point to the outermost exception?

Comment: i dont think there is an option - what are you hoping to accomplish? what is your end game?

Comment: @DanielA.White I want to confirm if the behavior is same in previous versions of .NET/Visual Studio, and if possible, to see "world" as the error message.

Comment: You can make a error like 5/0 and then you will catch the error because throw exception is not the error.

Comment: If it did, it would've been a bug. The try tries to run the block, if it isn't able to do so, it runs the catch. In your code it throws a new exception "hello", but there's no problem in throwing the exception, so "world" is unreachable

Comment: You may know this already, but if you don't include the ex parameter to the Exception constructor then you will get the result you are after.

Comment: I can't remember if this has changed, but I think it makes sense to show the inner most exception. Another option would be to log the errors in the global error handler, and in that log loop through the chain of exceptions.